# Count dropdownlist have value

Tags: drop-down-menu, count

I have 3 dropdownlist.

```
<select>
   <option value = "10">10</option>
   <option value = "20">20</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="30">30</option>
</select>
<select>
   <option value = "10">10</option>
   <option value = "20">20</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="30">30</option>
</select>
<select>
   <option value = "10">10</option>
   <option selected="selected" value = "20">20</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

I want use jquery or javascript to count number dropdownlist selected value = 30. In here return number dropdownlist = 2.

Comment: so what is you code to count it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not best solution, but I think its fulfill your requirement.

```
var count = 0;
    var ddlList = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var k = 0; k < ddlList.length; k++) {
        if (ddlList.value == '30') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    alert(count);
```